# Force an abstract class attribute to be implemented by concrete class

Tags: python, types, abstract-class, mypy, python-3.9

Considering this abstract class and a class implementing it:

```py
from abc import ABC

class FooBase(ABC):
    foo: str
    bar: str
    baz: int

    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = "bar"
        self.baz = "baz"

class Foo(FooBase):
    foo: str = "hello"
```

The idea here is that a `Foo` class that implements `FooBase` would be required to specify the value of the `foo` attribute, but the other attributes (`bar` and `baz`) would not need to be overwritten, as they're already handle by a method provided by the abstract class.

From a MyPy type-checking perspective, is it possible to force `Foo` to declare the attribute `foo` and raise a type-checking error otherwise?

**EDIT:**

The rationale is that `FooBase` is part of a library, and the client code should be prevented from implementing it without specifying a value for `foo`. For `bar` and `baz` however, these are entirely managed by the library and the client doesn't care about them.

Comment: Do you want `foo` to be a *class* attribute (as assigned by `Foo`) or an *instance* attribute (as assigned by `FooBase.__init__`)?

Comment: bear in mind that mypy won't check that the subclass calls the superclass's `__init__`, so `bar` and `baz` aren't guaranteed to be initialized either

Comment: @chepner in this case I guess the best is `foo` would be a class attribute?

Comment: @joel sure, here I want to focus more on forcing `Foo` to specify a `foo` attribute value

Comment: if it's a class attribute, `bar` and `baz` definitely won't be initialized at the class level in subclasses. But given your recent comment maybe you don't mind ...

Comment: @joel this is fine for `bar` and `baz`, they are handled entirely by the abstract class, which the client is assumed to trust. I edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: You still haven't clarified if `foo` is supposed to be a class or instance attribute. It's fine to make `Foo` responsible for setting its value, but if it's supposed to be an instance attribute, you should define `self.foo` in `Foo.__init__` (just like `FooBase` sets the instance attributes `bar` and `bar`), not define `Foo.foo`.

Comment: @chepner it should be a class attribute — there's always gonna be only one single class `Foo` being instantiated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a partial answer. You can use

```
class FooBase(ABC):
    @property
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(cls) -> str:
        ...

class Foo(FooBase):
    foo = "hi"

def go(f: FooBase) -> str:
    return f.foo
```

It's only partial because you'll only get a mypy error if you try to instantiate `Foo` without an initialized `foo`, like

```
class Foo(FooBase):
    ...

Foo()  # error: Cannot instantiate abstract class "Foo" with abstract attribute "foo"
```

This is the same behaviour as when you have a simple `@abstractmethod`. Only when instantiating it is the error raised. This is expected because `Foo` might not be intended as a concrete class, and may itself be subclassed. You can mitigate this somewhat by stating it is a concrete class with `typing.final`. The following will raise an error on the class itself.

```
@final
class Foo(FooBase):  # error: Final class __main__.Foo has abstract attributes "foo"
   ...
```

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't aware of this approach so thanks for this.

Comment: @Jivan see my extra comment on `final`, which might help

Comment: This answer no longer works in newer versions of mypy as tested on the mypy playground and explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75253719), along with work arounds. Worse yet, new versions of Python will **fail at runtime** as well, **breaking** any code which uses this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Previously, one the "solutions" to this type of problem was to stack `@property`, `@classmethod`, and `@abstractmethod` together to produce an "abstract class property`.

According to [CPython issue #89519](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89519), chaining descriptor decorators like `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod` with `@property` can behave really poorly, so it has been decided that chaining decorators like this is [deprecated beginning Python 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/functions.html#classmethod), and will now error with tools like `mypy`.

There is an alternative solution if you really need something that behaves like an abstract class property, as explained in [this comment](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89519#issuecomment-1397547060), especially if you need a property for some expensive/delayed accessing. The trick is to supplement using `@abstractmethod` with subclassing `typing.Protocol`.

```py
from typing import ClassVar, Protocol


class FooBase(Protocol):
    foo: ClassVar[str]


class Foo(FooBase):
    foo = "hello"


class Bar(FooBase):
    pass


Foo()
Bar()  # Cannot instantiate abstract class "Bar" with abstract attribute "foo"
```

Note that although linters can catch this type of error, it is not enforced at runtime, unlike creating a subclass of `abc.ABC` which causes a runtime error if you try to instantiate a class with an abstract property.

Additionally, the above approach does not support the use of `foo = Descriptor()`, similar to implementing an attribute with a `@property` instead. To cover both cases, you'll need to use the following:

```py
from typing import Any, ClassVar, Optional, Protocol, Type, TypeVar, Union

T_co = TypeVar("T_co", covariant=True)


class Attribute(Protocol[T]):

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None) -> T_co:
        ...


class FooBase(Protocol):
    foo: ClassVar[Union[Attribute[str], str]]


class Foo(FooBase):
    foo = "hello"


class Foo:

    def __get__(self, instance: Any, owner: Optional[Type] = None) -> str:
        return "hello"


class Bar(FooBase):
    foo = Foo()


Foo()
Bar()
```

Both classes pass type checks and actually work at runtime as intended, although again nothing is enforced at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on the user to set an attribute inside of the class body, you can instead mandate a value using `__init_subclass__` as proposed by [PEP 487](https://peps.python.org/pep-0487/). Additionally, you should use `typing.ClassVar` for class variables, otherwise it'll mix with instance variables.

```py
from typing import Any, ClassVar


class FooBase:
    foo: ClassVar[str]
    
    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, *, foo: str, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        cls.foo = foo
        return super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)


class Foo(FooBase, foo="hello"):
    pass
```

This syntax is clean for the user, especially when you need something more complex than setting a class variable like

```py
class Database(DB, user=..., password=...):
    pass
```

which could get setup to create a `Database.connection` class variable.

The one downside with this approach is that further subclasses will need to continue supplying the class parameters, which can usually be fixed by implementing your own `__init_subclass__`:

```py
class MainDatabase(DB, user=..., password=...):

    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, reconnect: bool = False, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        # Create a new connection.
        if reconnect:
            kwargs.setdefault("user", cls.user)
            kwargs.setdefault("password", cls.password)
            return super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)

        # Re-use the current connection.
        else:
            return super(DB, cls).__init_subclass__(**kwargs)


class SubDatabase(Database, reconnect=True, user=..., password=...):
    pass
```

Good linters should be able to recognize this type of pattern, producing errors on `class Foo(FooBase):` without producing errors on `class SubDatabse(Database, reconnect=True):`.

Comment: How would you impolment this logic but using decoratos? for example, force the classes implmenting it to declare a classvar named foo of type string and bar of type int:

@with_clasvars(foo:str, bar:int)
class FooBase:
    ...