# How to type hint a staticmethod+abstractmethod+property using Mypy in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Given this code:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

class Foo(ABC):
    
    @property
    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def name() -> str:
        pass

class Bar(Foo):
    name = "bar"

class Baz(Foo):
    name = "baz"

instances = [Bar(), Baz()]

print(instances[0].name)

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(instances[0].name)
```

Ran by the `python` interpreter, it prints (as expected):

```
bar
```

However, ran by `mypy` type checker, it prints (unexpectedly):

```
main.py:23: note: Revealed type is "def () -> builtins.str"
```

It looks like the type is wrongly inferred ([see playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=0.961&python=3.10&gist=5769925c4ace0e3f66337533fb42e27a)). Is it possible to fix that somehow?

If possible, I would like to fix it "once and for all" (like in the `Foo` class) because I'm accessing `.name` in multiple places.

Comment: you could use a `@classmethod` and just not use the `cls`

Comment: related/duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/72676882/5986907

Comment: @joel Nice workaround, thanks, it's working like a charm! Is it a known bug or should I opened a bug report on Mypy issue tracker, in your opinion?

Comment: I don't see how `@property` could work with `@staticmethod` since they expect different function signatures. I don't know if it is a bug or not

Comment: @Delgan The core issue is that `@property` and `@staticmethod` do not stack together well and is known to cause certain bugs, which is why [CPython issue 89519](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89519) has deprecated its usage and **will break code** in newer versions of Python. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75253719) for some alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3.11 disallowed wrapping of `@property` using class decorators such as `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` (see [GH#89519](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/89519)).

This means the provided snippet shouldn't be considered as valid Python code, and latest versions of Mypy actually warns about it:

```bash
main.py:6: error: Only instance methods can be decorated with @property  [misc]
main.py:23: note: Revealed type is "def () -> builtins.str"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

The easiest workaround is simply to use an instance method like so:

```py
class Foo(ABC):
    
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def name(self) -> str:
        pass
```

See also: [GH#13035](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/13035).